# negative to positive value when reading .txt file using read_table vs read.table

Tags: r, read.table, readr

I'm trying to read in a fairly large txt file, but when I use read_table from readr I noticed that the negative signs must be getting chopped off for some values.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(curl)

curl_download(url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WON53elbMVxAM8yWSg69nuu0cnHjaQdh', 
               destfile = '/Users/Jay/Desktop/1992_anomaly.txt')

dat1 <- read_table('/Users/Jay/Desktop/1992_anomaly.txt', 
                   col_names = FALSE,
                   col_types = cols(
                     X1 = col_integer(),
                     X2 = col_integer(),
                     X3 = col_integer(),
                     X4 = col_double(),
                     X5 = col_double(),
                     X6 = col_double()
                   ))
dat1

dat2 <- read.table('/Users/Jay/Desktop/1992_anomaly.txt', 
                   header = FALSE)
head(dat2)

# value from read_table that should be negative
dat1 %>%
  filter(
    X1 == 12 & X2 == 5 & X3 == 1295
  )



# value from read.table that's correct
    dat2 %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      filter(
        V1 == 12 & V2 == 5 & V3 == 1295
      )
```

Is there something I can change in the read_table function, or do I need to use read_delim to read this file in correctly?

Comment: Can you post the first couple lines from the file? It's very hard to answer *"do I need to use read_delim to read this file in correctly?"* without seeing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `read_table2` from `readr`